# Update vertex position in vertex shader opengl

Tags: opengl, shader, particles, vertex

I have a single VBO with the following vertex attributes:

```
3 floats for x,y,z
3 floats for r,g,b
2 floats for velocity_x,velocity_y
```

I'd like to apply the velocity of a given vertex to its position, in the vertex shader and have done this so far, but it doesn't seem to be applying any changes:

```
                    "#version 330 core\n"
                    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertexPos;\n"
                    "layout (location = 1) in vec3 vertexColor;\n"
                    "layout (location = 2) in vec2 vertexVelocity;\n"

                    "vec3 newPosition;\n"
                    "out vec3 vertexColorRes;\n"

                    "uniform mat4 viewMatrix;\n"
                    "uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;\n"

                    "void main()\n"
                    "{\n"
                    "   newPosition = vertexPos + vec3(vertexVelocity, 1.0);\n"
                    "   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);\n"
                    "   vertexColorRes = vertexColor;\n"
                    "}\0"));
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: What do you expect `newPosition` to do? It's a [per-instance global variable; it is entirely local to the instance](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Default).

Comment: How can I apply the new position to the actual vertex position in the VBO?

Comment: You don't. VS's *generate* vertex data for rendering purposes. They don't store data in accessible memory, and writing the data you're reading is never a good idea to begin with. There are ways to write data to buffers through the actions of a VS, such as transform feedback, but that wouldn't work in 3.30 as it lacks the multi-stream output capabilities needed to write values you don't intend to use for rendering.

Comment: @NicolBolas I want to move each of these particles by their velocity, every frame. Is there a way with 3.30 that I can do this?

Comment: The reasonable way to do that sort of things on the GPU is via a _compute shader_. However, that;s GL 4.3 level functionality. If you're really limited to 3.3, the usual implemantation would be to do the particle simulation on the CPU each frame. YOu could do weird hacks mis-using fragment shaders and render-to-texture + PBOs as poor-man's compute shader, but the utility and flexibility of that is very limited, while the complexity is quite high.